# How to avoid running out of memory reading a complex PDF via iText7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm using iText7 and Java to read PDFs that are not very large (10-30MB), but they contain a massive number of objects, causing `OutOfMemoryError` problems when creating and using a `PdfDocument`. (The internal `xref` table and `Map/Tree/Pdf[Dict/Array]` objects are in the millions.)

For example, a single PDF might only be 33MB but it contains a single table with a million rows spanning 800 pages, and the bookkeeping inside of `PdfDocument` is blowing up to 400MB. Here's the sample code and heap dump:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // PDF file is 33MB on disk (one big table over 800 pages)
    File pdf = new File("big.pdf"); // Also tried InputStream

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf); // 35MB heap

    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader); // 400MB+ heap

    // do stuff ... assuming we didn't get an OOM above
}
```

[image: Image of heap dump from a complex PdfDocument]

We added more memory to the JVM, but we don't know how big/complex some of these PDFs might be, so a long-term solution is needed, ideally one that lets us read contents in pieces or in an event-like callback manner (like XML+STAX/SAX).

Is there a more efficient way to either stream the PDF or break it up into sub `PdfDocuments` given a file or `InputStream`? We want to locate and extract objects like forms, tables, tooltips, etc.

**Update:** I got in contact with the IText team and IText7 doesn't allow partial readings of PDFs. So there isn't much I can do in this case except add more RAM or pre-parse the PDF mysql and look for "too much data" (a lot of work). I also checked `PDFBox` and it suffers from the same problem.

Comment: I think you split your PDF in minimum number of pages i.e. 100 or something more suitable to you and then do things

Comment: @Vineet1982 - I was thinking about a similar strategy, but then I ran back into the same problem: How do I split up the PDF programmatically (`PdfSplitter`) I can't even initially read it into Java without memory issues? The problem is I don't know where these PDFs are coming from or their complexity, so I can't manually pre-split them ahead of time.

Comment: Search the internet There are lot and lot of programs/code available to split the pdf programmatically. Splitting PDF doesn't need much memory and they are well created specifically for this purpose only. There are lot of c programs available with api which can be called from java

Comment: Maybe: small object pointers in 64 bit java once was a JVM option. Pruning of data: no (embedded) fonts, images minimized. A (commercial) PDF optimizers. Linux.

Comment: As mentioned in my update, there isn't anything IText7 can do to solve this problem. It would be nice if there was an event callback upon parsing objects, so calling code could count parsing progress and maybe throw an exception if there's too much data. But the API is very closed. I will continue to evaluate other solutions and toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following for reading large files:

```
RandomAccessSourceFactory rasf = new RandomAccessSourceFactory();

RandomAccessSource ras = rasf.createBestSource(file);

RandomAccessFileOrArray rafoa = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(ras);

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(rafoa, null);
```

Comment: I will use this for large files, so thanks! Unfortunately, the main problem I had in my original post is not so much the raw size of the PDF, but the complexity of the contents within and the internal book-keeping objects from IText's blowing up the heap. For example, even a small PDF of 10MB can be complex enough (nested objects, tables, etc) that to represent it within IText requires hundreds of MB of heap. In the short-term, I subclassed `PdfReader` and internally kept track of the `XREF` objects and stopped processing if we hit a limit. It's an awful hack but it kept the server safe.